# How to search in Json file attached in BLOB field using Oracle 12c?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, blob, oracle12c

I want search text inside of json. that json is persisted in blob field. I have created the follow table

```
CREATE TABLE APPLICATION
  (
    applicationId   VARCHAR2(36),
    customerId      VARCHAR2(36),
    assignee        VARCHAR2(36),
    status          VARCHAR2(36),
    applicationDate TIMESTAMP,
    closerDueDate   TIMESTAMP,
    closedDate      TIMESTAMP,
    application blob ,
    CONSTRAINT application CHECK(application IS JSON FORMAT JSON)) LOB (application) STORE AS(STORAGE (NEXT 15M));
```

To persist one row I've used the SQL Develop UI to add all fields value and attach the json file into blob field. The file attached in blob field has json text (huge json).

Example of file

```
{
   "fields" : {
        "Customerid" : "Organization"
   }     
}
//Huge Json
```

I want to search inside of blob field using path. Like: `fields.Customerid:"Organization"`

I am using the follow query but it's not getting any row

```
select * 
from application app 
where dbms_lob.instr(app.application, utl_raw.CAST_TO_RAW('AutomationRuleSet'), 1, 1) > 0;
```

I know that value exists inside json persisted

---

**Edit 1**

if I try:

```
Select app.application 
From APPLICATION app 
Where JSON_QUERY(app.application, '$.fields.CustomerID') = 'AutomationRuleSet';
```

I got:

```
Error que empieza en la línea 1 del comando: 
Select app.application From APPLICATION app Where JSON_QUERY(app.application, '$.fields.CustomerID') = 'AutomationRuleSet' 
Error en la línea de comandos:2 Columna:6 Informe de error: 
Error SQL: ORA-40499: no format defined for binary data type
```

what's the problem?

Comment: @AlexPoole if I try:

``Select app.application
From APPLICATION app
Where JSON_QUERY(app.application, '$.fields.CustomerID') = 'AutomationRuleSet'; ``

I got: ``Error que empieza en la línea 1 del comando:
Select app.application
From APPLICATION app
Where JSON_QUERY(app.application, '$.fields.CustomerID') = 'AutomationRuleSet'
Error en la línea de comandos:2 Columna:6
Informe de error:
Error SQL: ORA-40499: no format defined for binary data type``

Comment: Don't add code in comments [edit] your question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree with you, but according to the documentaion BLOB allow persist json. How do you know CLOB is the recommended format for JSON?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - [Oracle recommends that you use BLOB, not CLOB storage](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADJSN/overview-of-storage-and-management-of-JSON-data.htm).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but the doc recommend BLOB instance CLOB, however blob is difficult to works with command-line tools such as SQL*Plus. Also Clob iuso more byte.

Comment: @AlexPoole: ah didn't know that. That's pretty stupid though, because BLOBs are really hard to  work with in plain SQL - simply viewing the content is a lot easer with a CLOB.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - yep, no argument there *8-) Guess they aren't expecting JSON  to be viewed or manually manipulated much? Still, it's allowed, and the OP has the is_json check too.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I agree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can find rows whose JSON BLOBS contain the key path with [`json_exists()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions010.htm#SQLRF56664):

```
select * from application app
where json_exists(app.application, '$.fields.Customerid');
```

You can search for a specific value with [`json_value()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions093.htm#SQLRF56668):

```
select * from application app
where json_value(app.application, '$.fields.Customerid') = 'AutomationRuleSet';
```

As you're using a BLOB you may need to specify `format json`, though I dont' seem to need to while testing this in 12.2 and your table definition:

```
select * from application app
where json_exists(application format json, '$.fields.Customerid');

select * from application app
where json_value(application format json, '$.fields.Customerid') = 'AutomationRuleSet';
```

[Oracle Live SQL demo](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/ed4otwsi8icwihnrcuxrh3dzq).

Comment: i got ``Error SQL: ORA-40499: no format defined for binary data type`` error

Comment: How can I open the file an search the text?

Comment: Does adding `format json` help, with these or your `json_query` attempt? I've updated the answer to show where it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution:
I have found the solution, basically I had to convert the BLOB to VARCHAR2

```
select UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2( DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR( app.application, 4000, 1 )) AS aplication
from application app
Where JSON_VALUE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2( DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR( app.application, 4000, 1 )), '$.fields.Customerid') = 'AutomationRuleSet';
```

Other solution:

Use `JSON_TABLE` and create table with json field

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that. Did you still get the error with `json format` added to the function calls?